# google domain verification doesn't show up in google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, verification, google-search-console

In spite of having followed the steps for verifying my domain, it showed me a green tick at the end , I am not able to see it in the google cloud platform.

It keeps giving me this:
[image: preview]

Isn't my domain name supposed to be shown here?

The steps that I've followed are the following:

1) click the add domain button

2) Insert my domain in the textfield

3) Then I verified it with the CNAME method.

4) It congrats me for verifying my domain.

I still cant see it in my google account verified domains list!

Comment: You need to provide information about exactly what you're trying to do and what you've done so far. "following the steps" does not tell us what you've done.

Comment: Okay I will update my question!

Comment: did you verify your domain in Google Search Console?

Comment: @MethkalKhalawi Thanks for asking! It looks like i had to click the blue button "add domain" again and type the same domain after having verified it. Now I can see it!